# How to make sqlachemy see implicit lateral joins as in json_each or jsonb_each?

Tags: json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out the proper way of using json_each.  I've seen some tricks like using `column` or `text`. So far I've found a quite clean way using `table_valued`, that works except for the cross join warning.

```
term = 'connection'
about_exp = func.json_each(EventHistory.event, '$.about').table_valued('value')
events = s.query(EventHistory).filter(about_exp.c.value == term)
```

`EventHistory` contains one json field that looks like this: `{"about": ["antenna", "connection", "modem", "network"]}`

> The resulting query works as expected but I'm getting the following warning:
> SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "event_history" and FROM element "anon_1".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.

For any one that would like to experiment here is a working example in from of unit tests: https://gist.github.com/PiotrCzapla/579f76bdf95a485eaaafed1492d9a70e

Comment: Why don't you use a raw query?

Comment: This is a simplified example,  I would like to be able to join with other entities and use sqlalchemy implicit joins for that. But using text is one of the options.

Comment: I think that the more entities you join or try to use up-to-date SQL features the more cryptic and smudged sqlalchemy code gets. It seems  to me quite natural as you are expressing declarative logic (and there is a really good standard for that) in a proprietary imperative way.  Why shall one want to do this? BTW In this particular case no join is needed at all. `select <whatever> from "EventHistory" where "event"::jsonb @> '{"about":["connection"]}'`

Comment: the @> op is really cool, Thank you. And it gets nicely expressed in sqlalchemy too. My actual code needs json_each in select, hence I haven't though about alternative expressions but thank you! feel free to add this as answer to get vote up.

Answer (score 3):

So far the only way I found not to emit the warning is to add  `join(about_exp, true())`

```
    from sqlalchemy import true

    about_exp = func.json_each(EventHistory.event, '$.about').table_valued('value')
    events = s.query(EventHistory).join(about_exp, true()).filter(
      about_exp.c.value == about_val
    )
```

But it needs additional import of true and additional join statement, if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As of sqlalchemy version 1.4.33, you can use the `joins_implicitly=True` option for `table_valued`.

```py
term = 'connection'
about_exp = func.json_each(EventHistory.event, '$.about').table_valued('value', joins_implicitly=True)
events = s.query(EventHistory).filter(about_exp.c.value == term)
```

> `joins_implicitly` – when True, the table valued function may be used in the FROM clause without any explicit JOIN to other tables in the SQL query, and no “cartesian product” warning will be generated. May be useful for SQL functions such as `func.json_each()`.

[source](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.table_valued)